# how to get input fields name as an array using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have input fields,

```
<input id="member_name" type="text" name="member[$counter]" />
<input id="member_position" type="text" name="position[$counter]"  />
<input id="gender" value="Male" name="gender[$counter]" type="radio" / >
<input id="gender" value="Female" name="gender[$counter]" type="radio" />
```

And I'm using jquery to get the values,

```
var member_name = [];
    $("input[name='member[$counter]']").each(function ()
    {
        member_name.push($(this).val());
    });

    console.log(member_name);

    var member_position = [];
    $("input[name='position[$counter]']").each(function ()
    {
        member_position.push($(this).val());
    });

    console.log(member_position);

    var gender = [];
    $("input[name='gender[$counter]']:checked").each(function ()
    {
        gender.push($(this).val());
    });       

    console.log(gender);
```

All console.logs only returns "[]" that value. What did I missed out? Thank you

Comment: The radio buttons are not 'checked', so your list will be empty.

Comment: Hi sir, I'm sorry but what do you mean by that?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get a list of checked radio buttons, you must first 'check' one. Here I make the first radio button 'checked':

```
<input id="gender" value="Male" name="gender[$counter]" type="radio" checked="true" / >
<input id="gender" value="Female" name="gender[$counter]" type="radio" />
```

Now your array will contain the first radio button.

If you want to make an array of all radio buttons, then your JQuery should look like this:

```
var gender = [];
$("input[name='gender\\[$counter\\]']").each(function ()
{
    gender.push($(this).val());
});       

console.log(gender);
```

`Edit`:

I have added double escaping the attribute name (because JQuery misreads the string if it contains literal `Square brackets`.

Comment: How about in a input field text sir? I'm using the codes above but it returns no value.